# how to make axis title bold and change the font size simultaneously?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, themes, axis

I would like to bold the axis title as well chage the default font size of the title text. The problem is when write script for both font size and bold only font size chaged and the title doesn't bold and vice versa. I used the following code in ggplot2:

```
theme_classic()+
 theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size= 6, face = "bold"))+
 theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size= 6, face = "bold"))
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Maybe you could create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a working code which others can run and including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: I do not identify any problem here. Maybe size is too small so try increase the size.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works with increased size.